# Terraform error while creating principles

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to add principles to my template, below is my code

```
variable client_prod {
  default = 123456790123
}

output client_prod {
  value = var.cap_prod
}

variable client_non_prod {
  default = 987654321098
}

output client_non_prod {
  value = var.cap_prod
}

output client_prod_root {
  value = "arn:aws:iam::${var.client_prod}:root"
}

output client_non_prod_root {
  value = "arn:aws:iam::${var.client_non_prod}:root"
}
```

I am trying to create my principles like this

```
locals {
  principals = module.common-prefix.isPROD ? list(module.const.client_prod_root):
    list(module.const.client_non_prod_root, module.const.client_prod_root)
}
```

Later I am going to use it like this

```
jsonencode(distinct(local.principals))
```

I am getting the following error planning to terraform

```
Error: Argument or block definition required

  on main.tf line 46, in locals:
  46:     list(module.const.client_non_prod_root, module.const.client_prod_root)
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't break line** like that. It should be one line:

```
locals {
  principals = module.common-prefix.isPROD ? list(module.const.client_prod_root): list(module.const.client_non_prod_root, module.const.client_prod_root)
}
```

or use `()`:

```
locals {
  principals = (module.common-prefix.isPROD ? list(module.const.client_prod_root):
    list(module.const.client_non_prod_root, module.const.client_prod_root))
}
```